# Mixing string into the mysql query result

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database. Table `users` contains `user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`. Table `tickets` contains information about sold tickets and there is column `user_email`.

What I want to do now is to take all the users who bought the ticket and join it with the users table. The problem is that as a result I need to have a list of links that look like this:

`<a href='http://example{IdNumberHere}.com'> {FirstNameHere} {LastNameHere} </a>`

Is it possible to have a result like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CONCAT() function to join strings together, so something like

```
SELECT CONCAT("<a href='http://example", user_id, "'> ", first_name,
              " ", last_name, " </a>") AS addr
FROM ...
```

Should do the trick. You would then reference this concatenation as `$dbRow['addr']` in your PHP output.